# Input Values for Nativemethods.GetSystemMetrics Function in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, native-methods, getsystemmetrics

This function appears to be a way to access all sorts of system values.  For example
nativemethods.GetSystemMetrics(4096) returns whether a session is remote or local.  All I can find on the web are specific examples--does anyone know where I could find a complete list of input parameter values/what they return?  Seems that it could be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this page from PInvoke.NET](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SystemMetric.html) what you're after?